# How can I use navigation in material UI treeview.when I click on a leaf I need to navigate a specific page how can I do that?

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone help me with this:
How can I use navigation in material UI treeview.when I click on a leaf I need to navigate a specific page

Answer (score 0):

You cand do something like this

```
<TreeItem nodeId="2" onClick={()=> window.location.pathname = '/exmaple'} />
```

If you are using some router replace `window.location.pathname = '/exmaple'` with your goTo method.